# MemoryStream instead of byte[] for files added as resources?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, stream, resx

I have a .NET assembly to which i've added a number of files as resources (binary, >500KB each). I have previously been accessing these using the `ResourceManager.GetObject()` method on the auto-generated `Resources` class, which returns a `byte[]`.

For performance and syntax reasons, I would rather operate on these binary resources as streams instead of byte-arrays. I've found that, by manually editing the .resx file and changing the name of the class in the `<value>` element from `System.Byte[]` to `System.IO.MemoryStream`, i'm able to use the `ResourceManager.GetStream()` method to successfully access the resources as streams, e.g.

```
<data name="MyFile" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\MyFile.ext;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

becomes:

```
<data name="MyFile" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\MyFile.ext;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

The only drawback to this approach is that Visual Studio always adds new file resources in the `byte[]` form. Is there a way that I can get it to set the type to `MemoryStream` for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an extension method on `ResourceManager`.

```
public static class ResourceExtensions
{
    public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStream(this ResourceManager resourceManager, String name) {
        object resource = resourceManager.GetObject(name);

        if (resource is byte[]) {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])resource);
        }
        else {
            throw new System.InvalidCastException("The specified resource is not a binary resource.");
        }
    }
}
```

Calling

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
MemoryStream stream = resourceManager.GetMemoryStream("binaryResource");
```

Though, this seems just as well.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.SomeBinaryResource);
```

I'm not sure if I would modify the resource file since they are fragile to change, and I'm sure there are scenarios where Visual Studio will overwrite changes.

The problem with this, as per your concern, is that this creates a copy of the data into memory, creating a memory footprint. For lightweight resources that will be short lived, its a non-issue, but it can be a large concern.

The answer is short: You cannot avoid the memory footprint using a `ResourceManager`. The problem is that both `ResourceManager.GetObject(String)` and `ResourceManager.GetStream(String)` create a copy of the data. Even though `GetStream(String)` returns an `UnmanagedMemoryStream`, it actually makes calls to `GetObject(String)` internally, and a copy is still created. If you debug your application and profile the memory, you will see that the memory is still allocated.

I tried multiple ways to get around this by using pointers in an `unsafe` context, and reflection and nothing worked. `ResourceManager` is just not that flexible or optimized.

I was able to find a solution however, but it requires you to use `Embedded Resources`. This doesn't change anything, other than you setting the build action of your resource files to `Embedded Resource` for the `Build Action`. Using this, you can use reflection to create an `UnmanagedMemoryStream` that does not create a copy of the data.

```
private UnmanagedMemoryStream GetUnmanagedMemoryStream(String embeddedResourceName) {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    string[] resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    string resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(resource => resource.EndsWith(embeddedResourceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (resourceName != null) {
        return (UnmanagedMemoryStream)assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    }
    else {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("The specified embedded resource could not be found.", "embeddedResourceName");
    }
}
```

I did not test this extensively, but it does work. My test data was a small 17 megabyte file. The working set memory of my test application starts at around 50 megabytes, and after retrieving the resource into the stream, does not change. When using the `ResourceManager` it would increase the working set immediately by the size of the resource.

You will probably need to swap out the call to `EndsWith` that checks for the proper resource name in the manifest, because the names of the resources are slightly different than accessing it directly through the `ResourceManager`.

I am actually disappointed that I was not able to find a solution using the existing `ResourceManager`, but it just isn't flexible enough.

**Edit** I wrote an [in-depth blog article here about this subject](http://danderson.io/posts/getting-a-stream-to-a-resource-without-copying-the-contents-into-memory/).

Comment: I'm worried that, using your approach, the entire byte[] will be read into memory before the stream is constructed and returned. This is why I was hoping to be able to call `GetStream` instead of `GetObject`; to avoid reading the entire file into memory first.

Comment: I thought I had it, but I need to work on it a bit more. I'll update when I have something for you that works.

Comment: Updated my answer. In short you cannot avoid the footprint with ResourceManager.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into exploring the problem and testing solutions. With that in mind, I will probably switch to using embedded resources.

Comment: Glad I could help, this is going to turn into blog material where I will go more in-depth, but I had fun finding a solution. Hope everything works out well for you.

Comment: Added a link to the blog article I said I would write.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think you can prevent the secondary byte allocations now with UnmanagedMemoryStream if you can point to source in memory (ReadOnlyMemory<byte>), assuming that you can find it.

Example.) https://github.com/houseofcat/Tesseract/blob/6a3da2615b38b8e5526f5ccde568179df5a8ab9b/src/HouseofCat.Compression/GzipProvider.cs#L89

Above will allow one and only one allocation until the Developer uses the ArraySegment<byte> .ToArray() call in my example, but could return out the stream instead. Thus the only additional memory is the original Resource loaded.

9 plus years later lol.